# Prestashop 1.4.8 mobile compatibility

Tags: css, prestashop

I am using prestashop 1.4.8 version. I want  my website to be a mobile compatible.

Is there any plugins or frameworks like jquery mobile which can be added to my prestashop 1.4.8 version?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way is to use a responsive theme for your shop because Prestashop 1.4 doesn't include anything about mobile compatibility.
You can find good responsive themes for Prestashop 1.4 here : http://addons.prestashop.com/fr/3-themes-prestashop